# Codeigniter join two table based on two join conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, join

I am implementing the join query with code-igniter. I have two tables

```
 1) Users -> Contains all users
 2) Query -> Contains queries assigned to users. Each query has two users to attend that query.
```

In Queries table I have two columns

```
 1) attendingMD -> First user attending that query
 2) secondAttendingMD -> Second user that query.
```

I want to show the list of queries along with the name of both users attending that query. I managed to get the name if first user by using this code.

```
  $this->db->select("Query.*, Users.fullname as firstMD");
  $this->db->join('Users', 'Users.id = Query.attendingMD');
  $this->db->where('Query.isCompleted', 1);
  $query = $this->db->get('Query');
  return $query->result_array();
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.
Here is the view of table I want to show the table.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->select("Query.*, uf.fullname as firstMD, us.fullname as secondMD");
$this->db->join('Users uf', 'uf.id = Query.attendingMD');
$this->db->join('Users us', 'us.id = Query.secondAttendingMD');
$this->db->where('Query.isCompleted', 1);
$query = $this->db->get('Query');
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. You are amazing.